# Multiple UWP 10 projects within single solution with dependency of one in other not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

While trying to add dependency of one UWP application in other both having App.xaml wil not work.
It gives the following error

1. Conflicting values for resource 'Files/App.xbf'
2. Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry.

There are no resource files present.

> Is it possible to render the view like MainPage.xaml from first UWP 10 application in second UWP 10 application, and second application has the reference of first application?

The more description for the above problem is :-
The error occurs while building the project or solution. The OS version is Windows 10. And I am trying to run the application on Simulator.
Following is the process to reproduce issue.

1. Create new UWP10 Project say SampleParentApp.
2. Create new UWP10 Project say SampleChildApp.
3. Add reference of SampleParentApp in SampleChildApp. (SampleParentApp ->SampleChildApp)
4. Build The SampleChildAPP give the following compilation error.

> Conflicting values for resource 'Files/App.xbf'
>   Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry.

I want to render the xaml views from SampleParentApp while running SampleChildApp.
e.g. Run the MainPage.xaml of SampleParentApp from SampleChildApp

> **Note** - It works in one UWP 10 Application having the reference of other class library project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do that. Why not have a shared project with your MainPage.xaml in it to be references in both applications?

Comment: Could you specify your problem? What do you mean "render the view from first UWP 10 application in second UWP 10 application"?

Answer (score 0):

I have replied your same issue in MSDN:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4de8e299-f7f4-4cb2-8c6b-1ebc46aa27ff/multiple-uwp-10-projects-within-single-solution-with-dependency-of-one-in-other-not-working?forum=wpdevelop

You don't need to add a reference of a blank app template for reference the xaml file, you can create a class library according to the project template "Class Library(Universal Windows)" and add blank xaml page to this project.  To do this, you can use the xaml page in another project by adding refrence of the class library project.